# Append new item to end of list in scheme

Tags: list, scheme, let

I need to append a new item to the end of a list. Here is what I tried:

```
(define my-list (list '1 2 3 4))
(let ((new-list (append my-list (list 5)))))
new-list
```

I expect to see:

```
(1 2 3 4 5)
```

But I receive:

> let: bad syntax (missing binding pair5s or body) in (let ((new-list (append my-list (list 5)))))

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is mostly of syntactical nature. The `let` expression in Scheme has the form `(let (binding pairs) body)`. In your example code, while you do have a binding that should work, you don't have a body. For it to work, you need to change it to

```
(let ((new-list (append my-list (list 5))))
    new-list)
```

In my DrRacket 6.3 this evaluates to what you would expect it to: `'(1 2 3 4 5)`.

Answer (score 0):

A `let` makes a local variable that exists for the duration of the `let` form. Thus

```scm
(let ((new-list (append my-list '(5))))
  (display new-list) ; prints the new list
  ) ; ends the let, new-list no longer exist

new-list ; error since new-list is not bound
```

Your error message tells you that you have no expression in the `let` body which is a requirement. Since I added one in my code it's allowed. However now you get an error when you try evaluating `new-list` since it doesn't exist outside the `let` form.

Here is the Algol equivalent (specifically in JS)

```js
const myList = [1,2,3,4];
{ // this makes a new scope
   const newList = myList.concat([5]);
   // at the end of the scope newList stops existing
}
newList;
// throws RefereceError since newList doesn't exist outside the block it was created.
```

Since you already tried using `define` you can do that instead and it will create a variable in the global or function scope:

```scm
(define my-list '(1 2 3 4))
(define new-list (append my-list (list 5)))
new-list ; ==> (1 2 3 4 5)
```